# How to convert the user local time zone to server timezone using php?

Tags: php, timezone

I want to create a php script to conduct an online contest all over the world at single time .

My first question.. 
can i really do it at one time span , if yes then HOW?

for eg. let's say i host a contest for 10 jun 2012 ,from 2-4 pm IST or wherever the server is . Now i want that users from all over the world should attend contest at this time only . how should i tell user about  the converted local time zone of his? I dont want user should take pain for conversion of times and neither i'm willing to give a conversion tool for user's all over the world .

I want that user should enter the contest at his local timezone date and time being mentioned !.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

Get the client's Timezone by setting a cookie or using an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. Send the server time to the client (some hidden span or input.)

```
function getLocalTime(gmt)  {
       var min = gmt.getTime() / 1000 / 60; // convert gmt date to minutes
       var localNow = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); // get the timezone 
                                                      // offset in minutes            
       var localTime = min - localNow; // get the local time
       return new Date(localTime * 1000 * 60); // convert it into a date
    }

//var strDate = [get text date sent from server here];
var dt = new Date(Date.parse(strDate));
var localDate = getLocalTime(dt);
//[Set value of your localTime here]
```

Convert this time to users local time using javascript.
Display only the users local time to the user.

```
Contest will be held at : <span id='localTime'></span>
```

Comment: Your answer is incomplete if you don't show how to do the conversion on the client side

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies guys !!!

what to do if i don't want a change at client side ?
I mean every user at the any part of the world would login at server , when it would be 2pm ,on 10 jun 2012 at his local time .and there should be certain mechanism at server end which should detect the client's time and match whether data received from client at server end maps to the ongoing time of contest at client end and then proceed for further calculations.
please lemme know if there's a problem understanding my query !

Comment: You could always obtain the client time by javascript and send it as a request. But if you are designing a contest, that would be very easily hacked. I really recommend sticking to only one time at the server and using javascript to make it easier for the user to read as per his timezone.

Comment: if you ask your user what time is it at his place, and let me take a contest accordingly, i could lie(send wrong data) so that i get more time.